# Nested Recycler Adapter Items going into the wrong Recycler Views

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

On my app, I have a Recyler View with multiple recycler views inside. The inner recycler views are inserted dynamically. The issue Im having is that some items from some inner recycler views are going to other inner recycler views where there should be no items, like in the image below.

[image: Recycler views]

The top recycler view should not have those items while the bottom one is correct. I noticed that the items always glitch on the same recycler views, and after debugging I also noticed that on the glitched views, it doesnt even enter the sub adapter which makes it even weirder.

I should also mention that the sub recycler views are inserted based on volley requests. I make a request to an API and it generates the items. I have also checked and the API is giving the right response.

Fragment code (where the main recycler view is called):

```
RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String URL;

    RecyclerView catList;
    CategoriesMainRecycleAdapter adapter;
    List<String> cats;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

        catList = v.findViewById(R.id.crv_main_categories);
        cats = new ArrayList<>();
        URL = /*Removed this part for privacy reasons*/;
        Submit();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }

    private void Submit()
    {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject cat = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String a;
                        a = cat.getString("mCategoryName");
                        cats.add(a);
                    }

                    if (getActivity()!=null) {
                        adapter = new CategoriesMainRecycleAdapter(getActivity(), cats, (String) getText(R.string.website_link));
                        catList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                        catList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.login_communication_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.login_communication_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Main Recycler Adapter Code (this is where the sub adapter are called):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(capitalizeLetters(mCats.get(position)));
        holder.viewAll.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_forward_24_black);

        holder.lbl_error.setText(R.string.no_anime_with_category_error);
        holder.lbl_error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        holder.viewAll.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.image_click));

                        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, anime_category.class);
                        i.putExtra("Category", mCats.get(position));
                        mContext.startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
        );

        //Start the other recycler views
        URL = /*Removed for privacy reasons*/;

        String data = "{"+
                "\"mCategoryName\":" + "\"" + mCats.get(position) + "\"" +
                "}";

        Submit(data, holder);

    }

    private void Submit(String data, ViewHolder holder)
    {
        final String savedata= data;

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(mContext));
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    holder.lbl_error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    List<anime_class> animes = new ArrayList<>();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject anime = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        anime_class a = new anime_class();
                        a.setmNameEN(anime.getString("mNameEN"));
                        a.setmNameJP(anime.getString("mNameJP"));
                        a.setmDescription(anime.getString("mDescription"));
                        a.setmThumbnail(anime.getString("mThumbnail"));
                        a.setmEpisodeCount(anime.getInt("mEpisodeCount"));
                        a.setmOnGoing(anime.getBoolean("mOnGoing"));

                        //Add Categories
                        List<String> cats = new ArrayList<>();
                        JSONArray catArray = anime.getJSONArray("mCategories");
                        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < catArray.length(); i2++)
                        {
                            cats.add(catArray.get(i2).toString());
                        }
                        a.setmCategories(cats);
                        animes.add(a);
                    }
                    if (mContext!=null) {
                        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                                holder.rcv.getContext(),
                                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                                false
                        );
                        linearLayoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(animes.size());
                        CategoriesSubRecycleAdapter adapter = new CategoriesSubRecycleAdapter(mContext, animes);
                        holder.rcv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                        holder.rcv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        holder.rcv.setRecycledViewPool(catAnime);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.login_communication_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(error.networkResponse.statusCode == 404)
                {
                    holder.lbl_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.login_communication_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                return savedata == null ? null : savedata.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }

        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Sub recycler adapter (this part seems to work fine based on some debugging I did):

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(capitalizeLetters(mAnime.get(position).getmNameEN()));
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mAnime.get(position).getmThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.crv_.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, anime_page.class);
                        i.putExtra("mNameEN", mAnime.get(position).getmNameEN());
                        i.putExtra("mThumbnail", mAnime.get(position).getmThumbnail());
                        mContext.startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a trick that fixes the problem, but I dont believe its very optimized. On the Main Recycler Adapter, when I call the Submit method to get the data from the request, on the onErrorResponse I add 0 items, by creating an empty List and giving it to the adapter.

```
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(error.networkResponse.statusCode == 404)
                {
                    List<anime_class> animes = new ArrayList<>();

                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                            holder.rcv.getContext(),
                            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                            false
                    );
                    
                    linearLayoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(animes.size());
                    CategoriesSubRecycleAdapter adapter = new CategoriesSubRecycleAdapter(mContext, animes);

                    holder.rcv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

                    holder.rcv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    holder.rcv.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
                    holder.rcv.setRecycledViewPool(catAnime);
                    holder.rcv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    holder.lbl_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.login_communication_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
```